# Initialization during a pointer cast?

Tags: c++, c++11, derived

If I define a derived class which has initializers, but end up using pointer casts (i.e. static_pointer_cast), how can I get the initializers to be performed without performing dereference and then an object copy?

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class Base {
public:
    std::string Name;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    std::string Address = "Initialized";
};


int main() {
    auto b_ptr = std::make_shared<Base>();
    b_ptr->Name = "Fred";

    auto d_ptr = std::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(b_ptr);

    fprintf( stdout, "Name: [%s]   Address: [%s]", 
        d_ptr->Name.c_str(),  
        d_ptr->Address.c_str() );  // Address not valid!
}
```

Link to code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09f2240abff1556b

What is the proper way to handle this?

EDIT:   Below is some sample code (much simplified over the real thing, of course) that better illustrates what I am trying to do, and why it would be nice if there was a way to somehow make this work.

Updated Sample Code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdcc31a4417bb52b

In this example, I have two data sources, one is from a source system and the other is what is used internally.   I don't really want to copy all the data, just layer on some additional information to it.

I am not sure about using std::move (as suggested by @Mooing Duck) because of the consequences it has with the source data....something I need to explore more.   But from this example, the benefit of not performing a copy is clear, and having to use a "has-a" style implementation makes the subsequent object usage awkward.   I.e.:

```
test_row->Values[0].c_str()   and 
test_row->RowTotal
```

would become:

```
test_row->row->Values[0]    yet still
test_row->RowTotal
```

Perhaps I am looking at this all wrong and there is a better algorithm for doing this?

Comment: The object b_ptr points to is Base, casting it to a Derived pointer doesn't make it a Derived object, that's why Address is not valid.

Comment: I know that.   That was not my question.   My question is "What is the proper way to initialize after a cast."   Or should I do it differently?  I want to avoid dereference and object copy because the base class is quite large.

Comment: Wait... you are allocating a `Base` and then pretending it is a `Derived`? That's like buying a chair and then telling your blind friend "this is a couch, you can sit in any of the 5 places you like" then ask "why is he falling on the floor?".

Comment: @user3072517: There is no dereference or copy, but you'll need to add one.

Comment: I know....I am just trying to avoid a copy of all the base class members.   It can be quite expensive in the loop I am in.   Well, we did get 13 people in a VW once.   Does that count???  ;-)

Comment: @user3072517 You cant' initialize what doesn't exist. So instead of inheritance, maybe you can consider has-a relationship to avoid the copy?

Comment: 13 people in a VW, are you a clown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give `Derived` a `Base&&` constructor, and use it to move (shallow-copy) the contents of the `Base` into the derived, which leaves the origional `Base` in an "empty" state.

```
class Base {
public:
    std::string Name;

    //Note: The compiler is generating these invisibly for you:
    //Base() :Name() {}
    //~Base() {}
    //Base(const Base& r) : Name(r.Name) {}
    //Base(Base&& r) noexcept : Name(std::move(r.Name)) {}
    //Base& operator=(const Base& r) : Name(r.Name) {}
    //Base& operator=(Base&& r) noexcept : Name(std::move(r.Name)) {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    std::string Address = "Initialized";
    Derived() = default;
    Derived(Base&& b) : Base(std::move(b)) {}
};    

int main() {
    auto b_ptr = std::make_shared<Base>();
    b_ptr->Name = "Fred";

    auto d_ptr = std::make_shared<Derived>(std::move(*b_ptr));
    //NOTE AT THIS POINT b_ptr POINTS TO A BASE WHOS Name IS EMPTY
    b_ptr.reset(); //reset to prevent accidental errors with lack of content

    fprintf( stdout, "Name: [%s]   Address: [%s]", 
        d_ptr->Name.c_str(),  
        d_ptr->Address.c_str() );  // Address not valid!
}
```

See it working here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3a6062f6c459c7c
And also see proof of movement here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7f6cc4aa06d2746

However, it's worth noting that I can't think of a good reason you could ever want to do this.  It sounds like your code is poorly designed.

Comment: Very interesting!   I need to study this a bit more, but it seems like a pretty good solution.    I have to think about the implications of b_ptr having no content.    Thanks!!

Comment: This has interesting consequences, I think.  What if you create a new class Derived2 that is derived from base, then do: shared_ptr<Base> b_ptr(new Derived2());  What happens to the part of b_ptr that is Derived2 but not Base after you've moved the Base part out.

Comment: The only reason I think this may be useful is if you want to create a new object of a different type, but all the properties in the base are the same as an old object that you want to destroy.  When doing the new, you don't want to have to explicitly copy data over... However, it's not clear whether std::move's implementation doesn't actually just do memcpy.

Comment: @thang: I can't really imagine why it'd be useful, it seems like a bad idea all around

Comment: It is clear... std::move does not DO anything at all at runtime, let alone call memcpy. It only affects the value category of the reference, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. A *brace-or-equal-initializer* for a member is only executed by the constructor. You need to actually construct a `Derived` object if you want `Derived::Address` initialized. But you can't construct a `Derived` object over the space that's already occupied by a `Base` object; you'd have to destroy the `Base` object first.

Comment: So then perhaps a better way of asking my question would be something more like:    How can you create a derived object from a base object without copying all the members?

Comment: @user3072517: you could give the derived object a constructor that takes a `Base&&` and move it.

Comment: @MooingDuck Good call, this should work if every member of Base also implements move semantics.

Comment: And only if the Base instance is of no interest after the operation... ANyway I think that what he wants is "how to extend an instance of Base to obtain a Derived" : impossible.

Comment: Ok!  That might be the trick.   Any examples of doing this you could point me to?   In reality, this base class is actually nested deeply among other classes.   Do each an every class have to implement the move semantics all the way up the chain?

Comment: @user3072517: Only the ones that contain data you want.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the type in-place.  Not by doing extra initialization, or asking politely.  It is not possible.

This is very easy to see if you ask yourself

> How much memory was allocated by `make_shared<Base>`?

Comment: Well, it seems that I may have to convert to a "has-a" implementation.   That is unfortunate because it really follows a natural inheritance.   The size of the object is typically between 1-10k (depending on the data).   But, the rub comes in because there are 10+ millions (possibly even hundreds of millions) of these, and I was trying to minimize memory consumption.

Comment: @user3072517: Yes, has-a lets you share or steal the whole subobject without a copy.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I think it's more of an "is associated with", not "has a".  "Has a" has an implied 1-1 aggregation relationship.

Comment: Well, I just tried to turn it around to a has-a and I will say it is quite ugly.   My code goes from something that looks like this `Data->Rows[0]->RowID` to `Data->Rows[0]->Row->RowID` only because I need to add some additional members to the Row from another class object.   That seems such a mess.   I even went so far as to overload the Rows [] operator to make it look better, but I can't get away from a row instance.   A row instance now looks like `Row->IsUpdated` (for my overload, which is nice), but all the row members are now `Row->Row->RowID`.   Ick!